# Problem with the legend of ggplot2: Size of the points does not correspond to data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to do a scatter plot in which the size of the points corresponds to the diameter category (calibercateg) of each coordinate point.

However, this only works when I have a small amount of data. When I have more than 1000 points, the diameter written on the legend does not correspond to the actual values of the caliber/diameter categories (range 0-5 mm). What have I done wrong?

```
ggplot(My_data, aes(x, y, alpha=calibercateg)) +
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = ..level..), color="green", alpha=.1, geom = "polygon") +
  geom_point(shape=16) +  xlim(-2,3)+ ylim(-2,2)+
  theme_void()
```

Results:

When using 50 coordinate points

[image]

When using >1000 coordinate points

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. The size of all the points in both plots, and in the legend, are all the same. Only the `alpha` changes (i.e. the transparency)

Comment: Incidentally, you can use `geom_density2d_filled` to get nicer contour lines

Comment: The output would make me think your 2nd scenario has some rows of data where `calibercateg` is around 50, but most rows have calibercateg <10. Is that not the case? What is `max(My_data$calibercateg)` in the 2nd case?

Comment: Allan, the size of the points did not change, because I defined it as geom_point(shape=16). Thanks for the tip, geom_density2d_filled looks nice!